# what situation is right

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have two categories of people, the reliable and the liars.The reliable telling always the truth,the liars always telling lies. One visitor meets both of them:

A declares: "I and B are the same." B declares : "From us no one is reliable."

What situation is true?

a)both are liars
b) the A is liar and the B reliable
c)both reliable
d)A is reliable and B is liar

I beleive is the b) A is liar and the B reliable
Am I right?

Comment: What does "I and B are the same" mean here? Does it mean "we are the same person" (apparently false) or "we are of the same category"?

Comment: we are the same category

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear which group B is talking about when he says "From us". Perhaps "From us two, A and B"? Or "From my category"?

However, in any case: B is claiming to belong to (some) group that is *all liars*. If B is reliable, then his claim would need to be true, so B would need to be a liar also. Now that is surely a contradiction, isn't it? So it is not possible that B is reliable. He must be a liar.

Since B is a liar, his statement must be false, so the group is not all liars; it must contain at least one reliable person. Well, not B (he is a liar), but someone else.

Now about A. If he is reliable, then he is telling the truth, and he is of the same category as B, that is a liar. Contradiction. What about the other possibility? If A is a liar, then he is lying, and in reality he is of a different category than B; since B is a liar, A is reliable. Again a contradiction.

As it turns out the situation is impossible.

Comment: so I may have right to my answer?

Comment: No, the correct answer is "That situation is impossible". You simply cannot have those two persons saying those things, if all what you said about reliable people and liars is true.

Answer (score 1):

Now suppose $A$ is reliable then the statement "I and B are the same" is true. This implies $B$ is reliable. However, if $A$ was a liar then $A$ and $B$ are different thus $B$ is realiable. Therefore irrespective of what $A$ is $B$ is realiable. But if $B$ is reliable $B$ is also not reliable(from $B's$ declaration itself). Thus it's a contradicting situation.